# Solow Model With Land as Factor

Tags: macroeconomics, self-study, solow, steady-state, balanced-growth

Given the production function:

$$Y = K^\alpha (AL)^\beta R^{1-\alpha -\beta}$$.

Where $L, A$ grow at exogenously given rates $n, g$ respectively. $R$ is land and is constant in supply and given that $\alpha + \beta <1$. Investment is a fixed fraction $s$ of income so, $$\dot K/K = sY/K - \delta$$.

Question:

1. Show that there are two possible values (one positive and one negative) for $g_K$.

- I applied the usual aproach to find that $$g_K = \frac{\beta (g+n)}{1-\alpha}$$ at steady state. I think I didn't understand the question here because I don't see which two values are being referred to.

2. Does this economy have a unique and stable BGP? If so what are those growth rates and if not why?

- Again I could find the steady state growths buy it assumes that it exists. How to check whether it exists at all or not?

3. Does R being constant imply that permanent growth is not possible? Answer this using positive value of $g_K$ and deriving an expression for $\dot Z/ Z$ where, $Z$ is $Y/L$.

- No idea what happened here as couldn't solve (1).

Comment: Could you please show us the attempt for 2 and 3 per our homework/self-study question policy?

Comment: @1muflon1: as mentioned in the post the three parts are connected and I couldn't solve even the first part properly. For third part I am blank and for second I found rates as mentioned in the first bullet point. This isn't exactly homework but yes it is self study as I am trying to solve some questions. Would appreciate either: full solution or a good hint.

Comment: A good starting point would be defining $g_K$. Is that the growth rate at time t or the steady state growth rate?

Comment: As per question it is simply defined as $\dot K / K$. However it doesn't say that need not be a function of t